# How to display Integer values in a BlackBerry Table

Tags: java, user-interface, blackberry, components

i need to display values of the type "Integer" in a table.
now, what i thought to do, is to simply check for the type "Integer" in the "getDataFields()" 
method of DataTemplate and to set this DataTemplate as the datatemplate of my TableView.

The screenshot below shows you my "getDataFields" method. After running this code on a simulator i just get a NoClassDefFoundError.

Do any of you guys have any ideas how to do this?

*Setup: BB Eclipse Plugin v1.3, SDK 6.0*

[image]

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError will indicate what class it was looking for.  That's useful information for diagnosing the problem.   Also, a screenshot of code is hard to read.  Can you copy and paste the actual characters?   StackOverflow has syntax highlighting.

Comment: How can I look for the class it was looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go :)
(Note: I changed the type to Double instead of Integer, but it works the same way)

```
public void setStyle() {
    DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(tableView, NUM_ROWS,
            NUM_COLUMNS) {
        public Field[] getDataFields(int modelRowIndex) {
            Object[] data = (Object[]) _tableModel.getRow(modelRowIndex);
            Field[] fields = new Field[data.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i] instanceof Bitmap) {
                    fields[i] = new BitmapField((Bitmap) data[i]);
                } else if (data[i] instanceof String) {
                    MyTextField cell;
                    if(i==0){
                        cell = new MyTextField((String) data[i], RichTextField.NON_FOCUSABLE);
                    } else {
                        cell = new MyTextField((String) data[i], RichTextField.NON_FOCUSABLE | RichTextField.TEXT_ALIGN_RIGHT);
                    }
                    if(rowCount%2==0){
                        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(DesignColors.LIGHTBLUE);
                        cell.setBackground(bg);
                    }
                    fields[i] = cell;
                } else if (data[i] instanceof Double){
                    MyTextField cell = new MyTextField("Double", RichTextField.FOCUSABLE);
                    if(rowCount%2==0){
                        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(DesignColors.LIGHTBLUE);
                        cell.setBackground(bg);
                    }
                    fields[i] = cell;
                } else {
                    fields[i] = (Field) data[i];
                }
            }
            rowCount++;
            return fields;
        }
    };
    tableView.setDataTemplate(dataTemplate);
}
```

What I actually want to do is shown below:

```
Vector atx = new Vector();
atx.addElement("ATX");
atx.addElement(2885.19);
atx.addElement("-0,14");
kurse.addElement(atx);
```

So I'm filling the "kurse" Vector with several Vectors. The Vector in the example, "atx", contains different elements, Strings and Doubles. I need to pass them with different types, because Strings are going to be styled differently than Doubles.

Using the code above is giving me the NoClassDefFoundError, passing the value as String instead, like

```
atx.addElement("2885.19");
```

works perfectly.